# WF gets canceled status while WS call

Tags: workflow, development, web-services, json

I’ m trying to call HTTP WS from WF. Unfortunately, it gets canceled every time  and I can’t understand a reason. In a browser service works fine. Would you mind telling me what’s wrong?

WS source code:

```
    [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void GetData(string id)

{
    var l = new Login {Name = "MI"};
    var sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.Write(sr.Serialize(l));       
}
```

WF:

[image]

Comment: Finaly  I've found an exception message:                                     

RequestorId: e1c45fdb-4a52-0bf9-ac03-154e24738909.
Details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 404 {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["21"],
"SPRequestGuid":["22fe0d66-cdf8-4f70-91ac-1447548b5774"],"request-id":["22fe0d66-cdf8-4f70-91ac-1447548b5774"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],                               

Would you mind telling me a direction to look for a solution?

Thanx,Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue is solved! I tried the same WF at a site level (previously it was at a list level) and it completed without any problems. After that, I recreated a list and bound the WF to it. Now I suppose that the issue was related to some permissions on the original list.

Thanx! 
Alexander